# Using Jquery (or even just Javascript), how to chain commands together

Tags: javascript, jquery, chaining

There are several functions in jquery which you can do the following:
`$('#element').each().get('title').othercmd()`

How can I create a class ( or a series of classes ) to replicate this behavior?
Basically, I want to something like this:

```
test = new Something()
test.generateSection('title').addData('somedata')
```

What is correct for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach is to return "this" (the object) in each function. So you could do something like this:

```
<script>
var Something = function() {
  this.hi = function() {
    alert('hi');
    return this;
  };
  this.bye = function() {
    alert('bye');
    return this;
  };
}
var myObj = new Something();
myObj.hi().bye();
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Just return the thing that you are operating on at the end of each method. (`this` usually).

Answer (score 1):

You can implement a chain pattern just by returning the current instance in all the methods that you want to be able to chain.

```
Something.prototype.generateSection = function(title){
    ... code ...
    this.sectionAdded = ...;
    return this;
}
Something.prototype.addData = function(data)
{
  ... continue manipulating this.sectionAdded however you need it ..
  return this;
}
```

And do the same with the other methods of your "class". Something to keep in mind is that you must store the objects that you will need in future calls, in your case you are generating a section, so you would have to put that inside your instance (in some private variable like sectionAdded) so you will be able to continue manipulating it from other methods.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is a way to easily chain together commands with plain javascript, but if you wanna try this with jQuery, you'll have to write your code as a jQuery plugin.
It's actually pretty easy and there are tons of tutorials for writing your own plugins.

One of the easiest I came across is this tutorial:

[building-your-first-jquery-plugin-that.html](http://blog.jeremymartin.name/2008/02/building-your-first-jquery-plugin-that.html)